# Inconsistent output when running fortran program compiled with f2py

Tags: fortran, f2py

I have some fortran code which integrates a system of ordinary differential equations. I compile the code in two different ways: (1) with f2py, and (2) with gfortran.

When I compile the same program with gfortran, and run the program, the program always takes 97 time-steps to reach a specified ending time

When I compile the program with f2py, and run the same program it often also takes 97 steps to reach the specified ending time. BUT occasionally (~1/10 times) the program takes more than 97 steps to reach the ending time (~120 steps). In other words, the program is not consistent between runs.

Why is this? How can I fix it?

When compiling with gfortran (version 10.2.0) I use the flags "-O3 -fopenmp -freal-4-real-8"

When compiling with f2py (which uses gfortran 10.2.0), I specify the same flags but some extra are added by f2py. Below is the latter half of the f2py output.

```
compiling Fortran 90 module sources
Fortran f77 compiler: /usr/local/bin/gfortran -fopenmp -freal-4-real-8 -m64 -fPIC -O3
Fortran f90 compiler: /usr/local/bin/gfortran -fopenmp -freal-4-real-8 -m64 -fPIC -O3
Fortran fix compiler: /usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -fopenmp -freal-4-real-8 -m64 -fPIC -O3
creating /var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/src
creating /var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/src/modules
compile options: '-I/var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7 -I/Users/nicholas/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/nicholas/Applications/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c'
extra options: '-J/var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/ -I/var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/'
gfortran:fix: src/modules/Rainout_vars.f90
gfortran:fix: src/modules/reading_vars.f90
gfortran:f90: src/Photochem.f90
compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: /usr/local/bin/gfortran -fopenmp -freal-4-real-8 -m64 -fPIC -O3
Fortran f90 compiler: /usr/local/bin/gfortran -fopenmp -freal-4-real-8 -m64 -fPIC -O3
Fortran fix compiler: /usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -fopenmp -freal-4-real-8 -m64 -fPIC -O3
compile options: '-I/var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7 -I/Users/nicholas/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/nicholas/Applications/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c'
extra options: '-J/var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/ -I/var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/'
gfortran:f90: /var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/Photochem-f2pywrappers2.f90
gfortran:f77: src/lin_alg.f
/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -m64 -Wall -g -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle /var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/Photochemmodule.o /var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/fortranobject.o /var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/src/modules/Rainout_vars.o /var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/src/modules/reading_vars.o /var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/src/Photochem.o /var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/src/lin_alg.o /var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/Photochem-f2pywrappers2.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0/../../.. -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0/../../.. -lgomp -lgfortran -o ./Photochem.cpython-37m-darwin.so
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10/libgomp.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (10.15) than being linked (10.9)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10/libgfortran.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (10.15) than being linked (10.9)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10/libquadmath.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (10.15) than being linked (10.9)
Removing build directory /var/folders/rh/h610cb491m93m8kyz5br7gwc0000gq/T/tmp9cykppjq
```

Comment: Need to see the program.

Comment: @evets the code is here: https://github.com/Nicholaswogan/PhotochemPy. To reproduce what I discuss, compile code with `./compile.sh`, then run the test like 10 or 20 times: `python test_PhotochemPy.py`. Code should take 97 steps for most runs, but will take >97 steps ~1/10 times

Comment: I don't use python.  My guess is that f2py is not a Fortran compiler and mangles the code in a way that the dubious option -freal-4-real-8 longer promotes a convergence test to something that works.  I don't follow random links posted to SO.

Comment: Yes, please show a minimal example here. I agree that using `-freal-4-real-8` is a *very bad idea*.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was with uninitialized variables.

When the code was compiled with gfortran, for some reason, the uninitialized variables would always take `0` as "default" values. When the code was compiled with f2py, the uninitialized variables would sometimes default to `0`, but sometimes default to other values as well.

I found the uninitialized variables with `valgrind` (the -Wuninitialized gfortran flag did not catch them!).